# Use PsExec to run robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy, powershell-ise

Hi I'm currently making a script that copies a directory to another. I'm currently using this:

```
robocopy $splunkconfig 'C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps' /is /it /copyall /mir
```

But when I tried to combine it with psexec I'm having trouble making it work. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $PSExecExePath -ArgumentList @("\\$computer -e -s cmd.exe /c", "robocopy $splunkconfig \\$computer\c$\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps /is /it /copyall /mir")
```

and

```
Start-Process -FilePath $PSExecExePath -ArgumentList @("\\$computer -e -s cmd.exe /c", "`"robocopy $splunkconfig \\$computer\c$\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps /is /it /copyall /mir`"")
```

Any help would be great. thank you!!

Comment: What troubles are you facing? Please include any relevant errors

Comment: I actually am not seeing any error, it's just not copying the new directory.

Comment: You're missing quotes on the file path, which has a whitespace.  Have you considered simply using `%ProgramFiles%\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps` _(if using within a PowerShell terminal or script, command must be prefaced with `cmd /c`, as PowerShell does not recognize `%` variables, just as Command Prompt terminals don't recognize `$` variables)_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
psexec.exe \\$computer -c "robocopy $splunkconfig 'C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps' /is /it /copyall /mir"
```